# navigation bar in storyboard is mis-rendered

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode-storyboard

When I was trying to modify the navigation bar's title in one of my view controllers, Xcode seems to render the bar incorrectly, like below:


[image]

As you can see, the title and the rightmost button I added earlier are compressed in a strange manner. I tried to re-open Xcode, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I too an looking for answer to this....